# Best way to initialize Matlab parameters based on the machine

Tags: matlab, modularity, matlab-deployment

I am currently in a stage where I would like to have my code modularized and following software-engineering techniques to make it reusable and understandable. In particular, I run my code either in my laptop and in an external server.

My goal is to have the main part of the code exactly the same in the laptop and the server, but different initialization parameters in the two case (in the server I will increase the # of iterations for instance and other variables). What is the common practice to do so, apart from clearly an if-else statement in the main?

I was thinking of an initialization file (like a JSON) in the laptop and the server, which is different and I just need to modify the values. Or a Matlab function which initializes the variables, but still, it would have an if-else statement.

Other suggestions? Keep in mind I might to want to extend the algorithmic part and introduce new parameters in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Fair question but too broad for this site I think - maybe ask on the Mathworks forums.

Comment: You could use a config file containing the initialization parameters, so you wouldn't have an "if/else", just a different config file on each machie

Comment: But the config file you mean a script that returns the parameters? I would like some sort of plain text file or file sheet in which Matlab parse and fetch all data. How do people usually do in Matlab? In python there is a config file with YAML for instnace

Comment: Trigger with startup.m, actual data in global and persistent variables, static class fields, hash maps, you name it.

Comment: @wwweagle Can you point to some examples? I don't see how they fit in my case...

Comment: @VanBaffo e.g., "global iter_n;iter_n=50;" on laptop startup.m and "global iter_n;iter_n=500;" on server startup.m, other script just use "for i=1:iter_n", etc.